# Can I create an OS meant for a smartwatch without manufacturing the smart watch

Tags: android, operating-system, sony-smartwatch

I'd like to know if it's possible to program a smartwatch operating system without selling a watch that has it pre-installed (but is still easy for people to access and install on their watch) OR create an app that acts as an OS in a way.

For example, create an OS/app that takes over the watch to create a safe environment for a child to use. I ask this because all of the kid smart watches I've looked into are actually pretty bad and since I'm venturing into android development, I'd like to make this a project of mine.

Comment: Creating an OS is too broad for StackOverflow. That said look at [Kiosk Mode and how other dedicated devices are configured](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices) as you are using consumer hardware.

Comment: This is typically done using simulators. For example, the VMS operating system (32-bit) was developed on PDP-11's (16-bit) running VAX simulators.